# pushReplacementNamed not working in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

In `bloc` class, once the api return a success status, I want it return to logOut page. When back button is clicked, the app should exit.

```
 Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, LoginOut.ROUTE);
```

When I click back button, I expect the app will exit, but it back to previous page instead.  I thought `pushReplacementNamed` should work?

Answer (score 1):

I got a solution to this, by using this two code the problem solved

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(MainScreen.routeName);
```

By the way i got helped from this reference
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57579412/13827340

hope this could help someone ...

Answer (score 0):

When you use Navigate.push from firstPage to secondPage , and then use Navigator.pushReplacement to Navigate From SecondPage to thirdPage , In this case PushReplacement will not Exit your App. (it will pop from thirdPage to FirstPage).

Comment: I am using `pushReplacementNamed` form `splash screen` > `login page` > `splash screen` > `home page` so their is only `pushReplacementNamed` and not just `pushName`. so why this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add the below code:

```
Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/loginScreen', (route) => false);
```